# How to copy permissions from one user to another?

Tags: 2010, permissions

Is it possible to copy permissions from one user to another? The reason is that I have to give same level permissions to 50+ users and it becomes very time-consuming to do it for each user.

Any utility which eases this process will be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a group and add needed permission level to it. Then you can add your users to this group.

Comment: Also you need to ensure, that users belong to this group only.

Comment: Thx. I'm trying to clone an existing user and all rights previoulsy assigned to that user and grant all of those permissions to another user. The persmissions are deep and many, some permissions down to the file level, some permissions are for sub-sites with broken inheritance. I was hoping for a simplier way to copy all of the existing permissions.

Comment: Have you looked into using PowerShell at all? You 

Although, I would suggest (as a previous commenter did), since you are putting in effort to this anyway, to review the option of "fixing" the permission structure to be able to use groups. It will make things more manageable in the future, and depending on your situation, would probably be worth the investment.

Comment: 10 years later, is this still the recommendation for MS SharePoint? Use Powershell to copy permissions of a user to another? Trying to duplicate the permissions of a user within groups to another user - if this is still the answer than IMO MS is failing in it's capabilities to provide value.

Answer (score 2):

There is no OOTB way to clone SharePoint user permissions. You should either use 3rd party tools such as ShareGate, Axceler ControlPont, Boost Solutions's Permission manager or Use this PowerShell script way: Copy Permissions from One User to Another in SharePoint using PowerShell

[Copy Permissions from One User to Another in SharePoint using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/01/clone-sharepoint-user-permissions-using-powershell.html)

Comment: [ShareGate](https://support-desktop.sharegate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000597627-Copy-user-permissions#:~:text=Click%20Copy%20User%20Permissions&text=Select%20the%20user%20or%20group,to%20apply%20to%20the%20copy.&text=The%20task%20will%20now%20run.) is the answer that applies. I will inquire about access for this tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is permission cloning, copy the similar permission for all others. SharePoint OOB feature doesn't allow that, however, you can use object model or powershell script to do so. There are some third party admin utility tools available which can do this for you.